# Print range not working even if values are set

Tags: c#, printing, printdialog

I have a simple printing solution set up and normal printing works fine(tested it a couple of times), however when I use the PrintDialog to specify a custom page range, it is as if the range is ingored. When I debug I inspect the printDocument object and confirm that the range values are correct but the end product that the printer produces does not much the values I gave it.

Here is my code :

```
            printDialog.Document = printdoc;
            printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printdoc.PrinterSettings.FromPage = printDialog.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
                printdoc.PrinterSettings.ToPage = printDialog.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
                printdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange;

                printPreviewDialog.Document = printdoc;
                printPreviewDialog.FindForm().WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
```

*Note - printdoc is a instance of System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument. I added code in the PrintDocument's PrintPage event handler to populate the page I'm printing.

Comment: What is `printdoc`? Where do you call your `printDialog.Print___` function?  You're leaving out some possibly significant details.

Comment: It is a Instance of System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument. I added code in the PrintDocument's PrintPage event handler to populate the page i'm printing. Sorry i should have included this in my OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the print dialog that it should accept user input for page ranges.  To do this, you can specify the [`PrinterSettings.PrintRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printrange(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.AllowSomePages = true; //May not be needed
printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages; //Needed
if(printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // ... do the rest here
}
```

Notes: The main takeaway you should get is that you need to set `PrintDialog.AllowSomePages = true` (along with From/ToPage) in order to tell the dialog to only print those ranges.  Also, I am not sure if setting the `AllowSomePages` after the dialog closes will take effect, so that's why I put the code before `ShowDialog`.  You can try to set it inside the if-statement at your convenience.

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to solve the problem. Would have up-voted this answer but It seems that I cannot do so at this time.