# Print range is not working even if it's values are set

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, printdialog

I've written code for print the datagridview. But when I set the range of using "AllowSomePages = true" it still prints all the pages. Here is the code I've written for printing.

Already referred from below code but still not working.

[Print range not working even if values are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260116/print-range-not-working-even-if-values-are-set)

```cs
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();            
    printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;
    printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
    printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
    printDialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
    printDialog.AllowSelection = true;

    if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange;
        printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.FromPage = printDialog.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.ToPage = printDialog.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
}
```

Print Page Event

```cs
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Set the left margin
                int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
                //Set the top margin
                int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                //Whether more pages have to print or not
                bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
                int iTmpWidth = 0;             

                //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
                if (bFirstPage)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    {
                        iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                       (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                       ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                        iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                                    GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                        // Save width and height of headers
                        arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                        arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                        iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                    }
                }
                //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
                while (iRow <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow GridRow = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow];
                    //Set the cell height
                    iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
                    int iCount = 0;
                    //Check whether the current page settings allow more rows to print
                    if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                    {
                        bNewPage = true;
                        bFirstPage = false;
                        bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (bNewPage)
                        {
                            //Draw Header
                            e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                    Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                    e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                    FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                            String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                            //Draw Date
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                    Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                                    e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                    FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                    e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                    FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                            //Draw Columns                 
                            iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                    new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                    (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                    new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                    (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                    new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                    new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                    (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                                iCount++;
                            }
                            bNewPage = false;
                            iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                        }
                        iCount = 0;
                        //Draw Columns Contents                
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                        {
                            if (Cel.Value != null)
                            {                               
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                            new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin,
                                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                            }
                            //Drawing Cells Borders 
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                    iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                            iCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    iRow++;
                    iTopMargin += iCellHeight;                    
                }                

                //If more lines exist, print another page.
                if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                else
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are the minimumPage and maximumPage properties set?

Comment: We need to see the `PrintPage` event handler method, but I suspect that you did not pay attention to the 2nd paragraph of this [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printrange?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).

Comment: I used minimumPage & maximumPage properties but still it prints all pages and I've mentioned PrintPage event handler method TnTinMn